# git commit and push to branch but not to pull request

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I am working on a slideshow feature for an app and I create a branch off of `main` called `slideshow`. I know I have to submit a pull request to `main` directing it to pull from `slideshow`. In the pull request, conversation about certain aspects of `slideshow` delay the pull into `main`, but I still have to work on other aspects of `slideshow` for what will eventually be a separate pull request. So:

- I want to be able to commit and push to `slideshow` without it being included in the pull request I submitted
- But I also want to be able to go back and improve on the pull request for `slideshow` should code reviewers require improvements

Is there a way to push to a branch that's in pull request without pushing to that pull request? Or is the answer to this scenario to just create another branch off of `slideshow`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pull requests always contain all commits from the branch to be merged, so no, there is no way to push to a pull-requested branch without pushing to the pull request. The best solution is probably to create a new branch off of `slideshow`. I would suggest creating a branch specifically for the pull request, e.g. `slideshow-pr1` (future intermediate pull requests from `slideshow` could use branches `slideshow-pr2` &c., before finally merging `slideshow`); continue working on the slideshow in `slideshow`, and either cherry-pick commits from the original feature branch or commit directly to the pull request branch to improve the pull request, merging it back into the feature branch after the pull request has been merged into `master`.

Comment: I like the idea of creating PR-specific branches, that way you can easily cherry-pick commits from the progress. You could also know that it is safe to close the branch after the intended merge and know you aren't deleting any WIP.

Comment: It also keeps the tree nice and clean, and main development on the slideshow feature stays in one branch. It's kinda the same idea as `git-flow`'s release branch idea, except instead of development <-> release -> master, it's feature <-> PR -> master.